# Relationship between number of training set and classification performance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, text-mining, bounds

Are there any research/paper on the relationship between the number of documents for training and the classification performance using support vector machine?

Answer (score 1):

In general, in order to achieve better classification results, your database should not contain less than 40 inputs (where you will take 40% for training). It is because if you have less inputs you will have redundancy among your results and you should have constant results in order to prove your hypothesis.

---

These links contain number of SVM papers:

[svms.org](http://svms.org/top100.html)

[kernel-machines/papers](http://www.kernel-machines.org/publications)